How to expand the double integral in variational objective function?
I am reading John Paisley's lecture note on variational inference. In lecture 6 p.3, he wrote the objective function as follows:

Latex:
$$
\mathcal{L}(a', b', \mu', \Sigma') = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} q(w,a) \ln \frac{p(y, w, \alpha| X)}{q(w,a)} dw d \alpha \\
= \int q(\alpha) \ln p(a) da +  \int q(w) \ln p(w) dw \\
+  \sum_{i=1}^{N}  \int\int q(\alpha)q(w) \ln p(y_i | x_i, w, \alpha ) dwd\alpha \\
-  \int q(\alpha) \ln q(\alpha) d\alpha -  \int q(w) \ln q(w) dw
$$
How could he expand the double integral as one integral and summation of double integration? What techniques did he use? Is it related to partial integration?

Please don't use images of math.  Those are not accessible to people with visual impairments.  Instead, please transcribe them using Mathjax/Latex.  Thank you.

Sorry for inconvenience I caused. I will update it after go back home.

We have $$p(y, w, \alpha|x) = p(\alpha) p(w)\prod_{i=1}^Np(y_i|x_i, w, \alpha)\tag{1}$$
$$q(w,\alpha)=q(\alpha) q(w)=Gamma(\alpha|a'b')Normal(w|\mu',\Sigma') \tag{2}$$
Hence
\begin{align}&\int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} q(w,\alpha)\ln \frac{p(y,w,\alpha|X)}{q(w,\alpha)}dwd\alpha \\
&=\int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} q(w)q(\alpha)\ln \frac{p(\alpha) p(w)\prod_{i=1}^Np(y_i|x_i, w, \alpha)}{q(w)q(\alpha)}dwd\alpha\\
&=\int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} q(w)q(\alpha)[\ln p(\alpha) + \ln p(w) + \sum_{i=1}^N \ln (p(y_i|x_i, w, \alpha)  - \ln q(w) - \ln q(\alpha)]dwd\alpha \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} q(w)q(\alpha)\ln p(\alpha) dwd \alpha + \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}q(w)q(\alpha)\ln p(w) dwd \alpha\\& + \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\sum_{i=1}^N q(w)q(\alpha)\ln (p(y_i|x_i, w, \alpha) dwd \alpha  -\int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} q(w)q(\alpha)\ln q(w) dwd \alpha \\&- \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}q(w)q(\alpha)\ln q(\alpha)dwd\alpha  \\
&= \int_0^\infty  q(\alpha)\ln p(\alpha) d \alpha + \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}q(w)\ln p(w) dw\\& + \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\sum_{i=1}^N q(w)q(\alpha)\ln (p(y_i|x_i, w, \alpha) dwd \alpha  -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} q(w)\ln q(w) dw \\&- \int_0^\infty q(\alpha)\ln q(\alpha)]d\alpha  \\
\end{align}
The explanation is as follows:

In the first equation: We replace those terms with equation  (1) and (2).
In the second equation, we use the properties of logarithm to convert logarithm of product to summation of logarithms.
In the third equation, we split out integration terms into summation of multiple integration.
In the last equation, to convert those double integral to single integral, the technique used is when we integrate a density function over its domain, it is equal to $1$. For example, for the first term. $$\int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} q(w)q(\alpha)\ln p(\alpha) dwd \alpha = \int_0^\infty q(\alpha)\ln p(\alpha) d \alpha \color{red}{ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} q(w) dw} = \int_0^\infty  q(\alpha)\ln p(\alpha) d \alpha $$ where the red part is evaluated to be $1$.

